# Golang vs JavaScript (v8/node.js) map performance

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary, data-structures, go

Out of curiosity I wrote some trivial benchmarks comparing the performance of golang maps to JavaScript (v8/node.js) objects used as maps and am surprised at their relative performance.  JavaScript objects appear to perform roughly twice as fast as go maps (even including some minor performance edges for go)!

Here is the go implementation:

```go
// map.go
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"
func elapsedMillis(t0, t1 time.Time) float64 {
  n0, n1 := float64(t0.UnixNano()), float64(t1.UnixNano())
  return (n1 - n0) / 1e6
}
func main() {
  m := make(map[int]int, 1000000)
  t0 := time.Now()
  for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
    m[i] = i     // Put.
    _ = m[i] + 1 // Get, use, discard.
  }
  t1 := time.Now()
  fmt.Printf("go: %fms\n", elapsedMillis(t0, t1))
}
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```javascript
#!/usr/bin/env node
// map.js
function elapsedMillis(hrtime0, hrtime1) {
  var n0 = hrtime0[0] * 1e9 + hrtime0[1];
  var n1 = hrtime1[0] * 1e9 + hrtime1[1];
  return (n1 - n0) / 1e6;
}
var m = {};
var t0 = process.hrtime();
for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
  m[i] = i; // Put.
  var _ = m[i] + 1; // Get, use, discard.
}
var t1 = process.hrtime();
console.log('js: ' + elapsedMillis(t0, t1) + 'ms');
```

Note that the go implementation has a couple of minor potential performance edges in that:

1. Go is mapping integers to integers directly, whereas JavaScript will convert the integer keys to string property names.
2. Go makes its map with initial capacity equal to the benchmark size, whereas JavaScript is growing from its default capacity).

However, despite the potential performance benefits listed above the go map usage seems to perform at about half the rate of the JavaScript object map!  For example (representative):

```
go: 128.318976ms
js: 48.18517ms
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong with go maps or somehow comparing apples to oranges?

I would have expected go maps to perform at least as well - if not better than JavaScript objects as maps.  Is this just a sign of go's immaturity (1.4 on darwin/amd64) or does it represent some fundamental difference between the two language data structures that I'm missing?

**[Update]**

Note that if you explicitly use string keys (e.g. via `s := strconv.Itoa(i)` and `var s = ''+i` in Go and JavaScript, respectively) then their performance is roughly equivalent.

My guess is that the very high performance from v8 is related to a specific optimization in that runtime for objects whose keys are consecutive integers (e.g. by substituting an array implementation instead of a hashtable).

I'm voting to close since there is likely nothing to see here...

Comment: I'm not sure Go is not hashing the numbers, and I'm not sure javascript does the same. A map of consecutive integers between 0...1M is basically an array. Initializing m as an array of 1M ints, reduces the execution time to 2ms. Now do this benchmarks with strings and it's a real comparison. I won't be surprised if v8's speed would be faster then as well.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: ya I was kinda guessing that go might use int keys directly instead of hashing them; I suppose I could read the hashtable implementation to find out.  Funny enough - if I use string keys in both languages (using `s:=strconv.Itoa(i)` and `var s=''+i`) then they perform roughly equally; though using a numeric key in js is still much faster.  Many mysteries afoot here...

Comment: "*JavaScript will convert the integer keys to string property names.*" - no it doesn't. Even if they are equivalent, that's not what the engine does. It soon realizes that you are abusing an object for an array, and will use an array underneath.

Comment: @Bergi: yes, that would explain a lot (see my comment to @Not_a_Golfer).  It looks like this silly benchmark might be flexing a well optimized part of the v8 engine...

Comment: @Bergi's explanation makes sense. Your Go is idiomatic, I highly doubt any scripting language can actually out perform it.

Comment: @maerics It doesn't surprise me at all that when we're comparing both with strings, the map implementation of both performs roughly the same. V8 is highly optimized, and you know, you're basically benchmarking two hash table implementations in compiled languages.

Comment: BTW, in Go it's easier and better to use the [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) package for benchmarks.

Comment: Yes, looks like there's nothing to see here - please vote to close...

Answer (score 4):

Your benchmark is synthetic a bit, just like any benchmarks are. Just for curious try

```
for i := 0; i < 1000000; i += 9 {
```

in Go implementation. You may be surprised.

Comment: Hmm, yes, interesting.  Incrementing by other-than-one seems to defeat the v8 optimization that I suspect increment-by-one encounters (e.g. using an array implementation instead of a hash table).

Comment: Go maps are implemented precisely as hash tables(no arrays any way) and incrementing keys by one you just trying to model Pathological Data Set with much collisions.

Comment: So your suggestion is to execute **all** loop steps in JS, but let Go skip 89% of iterations and benchmark that? Very funny approach with very "suprising" results :D